# Using shebang in a spec file without it being a comment

Tags: rpmbuild

I need to make a small wrapper script around the binary I'm packing in an RPM. That wrapper script needs to say "#!/bin/sh" at the top. But when I do that, the "#..." is treated like a comment. No, don't comment that.

Is there any way to use a predefined variable or escape sequence to make a shebang (on the first line)?

Here's my little code in the .spec file:

```
%build
echo #!/bin/bash                                     > foobar
echo export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/foobar/foobar/lib  >> foobar
echo /opt/foobar/lib/foobar                         >> foobar
echo exit $?                                        >> foobar
```

... where the result of the 1st line in the %build cycle is simply "+ echo."

Must I take a different approach? If so, what approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just coming back to my question.

Quote the hash-bang. 'nuff said.Thanks.